# I need to optimize the storage of JSON into database Android

Tags: android, json, sqlite, realm

I need the faster way to store huge data in database android, I'm using SQLite such as a database and I use Jackson for Json.

I heared that I could optimize this processus, so can you suggest me a solution ?

- Does any one had the same problem?
- I found RealM but I did not test it.

Waiting for your help.

Comment: You must use transactions for insertions wherever possible and applicable. [Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/turbocharge-your-sqlite-inserts-on-android/) is a nice tutorial.

Comment: thanks sir, but i need to optimize more than transactions, otherwise if there's any library to speed up the querries.

Comment: Check it out with transactions, that would be the first step towards your goal. After you are done with that, you can check your program with traceview to get hold of all the bottlenecks. You must implement the Debug class to use traceview.

Comment: that's sound great, i'll try it

Comment: ohhh man you need a medal for your reponse, really I apperciate that :)